# Access Functions Attach in Drupal Behaviors From Global Scope

Tags: 7, javascript

I have this Drupal Behaviors Javascript code:

```
Drupal.behaviors.myid_templates = {
    attach: function(context, settings){
        function local_function(){
            alert('local_function');
        }
    }
}

function global_function(){
    //I want to call local_function here. Is that possible?
    local_function();
}
```

I was wondering I could do something like `Drupal.behaviors.myid_templates.local_function()` to access local functions from global functions? Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: This is a valid Question, why the downvote ??

Answer (score 4):

You would need to add it to `Drupal.behaviors.myid_templates` and not inside of your attach function.

```
Drupal.behaviors.myid_templates = {
  attach: function(context, settings){
    // Code to run on DOM ready, each AJAX request finish.
  },
  local_function: function (){
    alert('local_function');
  }
}
```